# Passing variable values over to paypal's cart for payment

Tags: php, paypal

I have created a basket where a user can add to and update etc. This basket has been built based on what product the user adds to cart obviously. The product itself is grabbed from the database and displayed in a table in the basket. How do I use Paypal from here? I now want a button called 'pay' that the user can click and then it takes them to Paypal to pay. But I want the details of the items to be displayed in Paypal.

I have signed up to paypals web standard payment. Obviously I don't need their add to cart buttons since I have got my own cart. I think I just need the buy button but as mentioned, I am not sure how to get products over to Paypal.

Can somebody explain what I need to do please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This broad of a topic is generally best suited with [a quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=paypal+integration). Basically, find a paypal form (perhaps through Paypal's button builder) and edit the form's values to suit your needs. This can be accomplished with php or javascript quite easily (PHP is a bit safer as it limits tampering). Then users send the form :)

You can also create a link such as`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&amp;business=$business` which will do the same as the full form (add all of the fields you want to send, of course).

Give it a shot - if you have more specific questions, post back with clarifications.